Cannot migrate from JBoss 6.4 to JBoss 7.1 in unitary tests: javax.naming.CommunicationException in the lookup
I have a test class with EJB that works with JBoss 6.4.
This is the pom:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

This is the code:
protected static Context namingContext;
protected static EjbCallerContext ejbCtx = null;

protected static final String BASE_URL = "http//localhost:8080";
protected static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:4447";
protected static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";

protected static Properties crProperties() {
    Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
    jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
}

public static void crProperties() throws NamingException {
    Properties pp = getPpProperties();
    namingContext = new InitialContext(pp);
    
    ejbCtx = new EjbCallerContext("prova", "prova");
}

In the test class, I connect to an interface with an EJB for tests:
private static final String REMOTE_JNDI_NAME = "ProvaEjb!ejb.ProvaeInterface";  
ProvaInterface= (ProvaInterface) namingContext.lookup(REMOTE_JNDI_NAME);

In JBoss 7.1, I get this error in lookup:

javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:4447 (Operation failed with status WAITING after 5000 MILLISECONDS)] [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Operation failed with status WAITING after 5000 MILLISECONDS]

I think the properties are the problem, so I tried changing to:
PROVIDER_URL = "remote://localhost:4447"

Also I tried:
PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://localhost:4447"

I added:
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, root);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, root);

But it still didn't work. How can I resolve this?

PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080"; (wildfly)


org.jboss.as
jboss-as-ejb-client-bom
7.1.3.Final
pom

Thank you for your answer.Tried that, didnt work

With this update, i have this exception:

javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080 (java.io.IOException: For now upgrade responses must have a content length of zero.)]

I'm sorry, the content I provided previously was based on tests of wildfly 17 and JDK 1.8; there is a big gap between jboss 7.1 and wildfly 17, so don't use the content I provided.

JBoss AS 7.1 Examples EJB
https://github.com/lnewson/quickstart/tree/7.1.0.Final/ejb-remote
